# What is the DC to spot a ruby carried by a gremlin, from 50 feet away?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, difficulty-class

What would be the DC to spot a ruby on a gremlin from 50 feet away, assuming optimal lighting and environmental conditions? Let's say he was just holding in his hand, and the ruby is about a Grade 4 (so about golf ball size?).

I set it at 10 plus 5 for distance = 15, and two PCs successfully spotted it. I'm OK with that outcome of that spot ruling, but I'd like to do it more correctly next time.

I suppose it was a Grade 4 gemstone. http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/appendix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base DC to [spot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) a creature that's out in the open is 0, and I think it's safe to say the same is true of objects. There's a penalty of -1 to the check for every 10 feet between the observer and the target. In your case, 50 feet, so -5 (or effectively, DC +5).

A creature using Stealth would benefit from a size modifier, but the ruby isn't hiding, nor is the gremlin attempting to conceal it. So your total DC *should* be 5. If you want it to be higher, the gremlin should have [concealed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/sleight-of-hand) it.

Comment: A minor issue I have with this answer is that the ruby **wouldn't** be in the open, as the gremlin would have it in his hands.  It might not be much harder to see the ruby if it is large enough that it couldn't be covered by his hand, but it would be more difficult.  For instance, if a 6 ft tall person was carrying a baseball in one hand, you could probably tell he was holding something pretty easy, but telling **what** that something was would be far more difficult because its obscured by his hand.

Comment: The mechanics do not address this. If the object is not using the Stealth skill, the only penalty is distance. Cover does not provide Perception penalties.

Comment: I would, at the very least, say it would be unfavorable conditions as by the modifier on the page you linked.  Also, I don't think you can necessarily apply the visible creature template to all objects they are holding, otherwise you would immediately see a worn ring or their socks, etc... because the creature isn't stealthing.  What you propose is a decent base, but I believe there are more circumstantial points you're not taking into account.

Answer (score 1):

The [Perception](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/perception.html#perception) check DC to spot the ruby would be:

- 0: Detect a visible creature
- +5: target is 50 feet away (+1 per 10 feet)
- -2: target is in a bright light condition and you must notice something reflective it is carrying on one of it's hands.

> 1 Favorable and unfavorable conditions depend upon the sense being used to make the check. For example, **bright light might decrease the DC of checks involving sight**, while torchlight or moonlight might increase the DC. Background noise might increase a DC involving hearing, while competing odors might increase the DC of a check involving scent.

- Total: DC 3

Yes, it's not difficult to notice that he has a ruby on his hands, but someone *might* fail. It's those things you mention when describing the encounter: *You see a small creature, greenish, with long pointy ears and battered leather and fur clothes, it holds a small blade, maybe a dagger, on one hand and a red gem on the other.*

If you look at the tables for Vision on the [Exploration and Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement) rules, it says:

> **Bright Light**
>
> In an area of bright light, **all characters can see clearly**. Some creatures, such as those with light sensitivity and light blindness, take penalties while in areas of bright light. A creature can't use Stealth in an area of bright light unless it is invisible or has cover. Areas of bright light include outside in **direct sunshine** and inside the area of a daylight spell.
>
> Bright light is created by direct sunlight, as well as by spells such as daylight.
>
> **Color and detail are easily determined** by most creatures in bright light, though shiny or reflective surfaces can be difficult to look at.
>
> It is impossible for characters in bright light to attempt Stealth checks without cover or invisibility.

However, this is to notice a gem that is open for everyone to see, if this gremlin is holding it in his hands and it's difficult to see, you can apply some [Stealth Modifiers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth) to increase this DC. Do note that this is not RAW and merely subject to my interpretation of the situation. But to explain why im applying this modifier, it is applied to a stealth check regardless of the skill ranks or the ability of the creature performing it, so even if it rolls a 1 on the d20, it still grants that bonus. Thus we can treat that as a passive bonus that can be applied to perception checks.

To notice the gremlin would be a DC 7 check (3 + 4 for a *small creature*), easily done with a take 10 check.
To notice the small gem on his clasped hands would be a **DC 19** (3 + 16 for a *fine object*), hardly easy unless this character is focused on perception. But it's not impossible either even for lv1 characters.

In general, you shouldn't use Perception checks for something that is simple to spot. If you want to make a check, you need some factor to make it tricky and harder to spot.

Comment: The perception rules you are citing are obviously wrong: bright light should give you a bonus, and not increase the DC. One could argue about this very point, but could he argue that background noise should reduce the DC, as mentioned in the SRD ? It seems the whole paragraph sould be read replacing "increase" by "decrease", and so on.

Comment: Bright light gives a penalty when they get in the way, such as looking at the surface of a lake, or a mirror, or something shiny. You never had to drive when facing the sun?

Comment: If you read again, i cited the bright light rules explicity because they say you cannot stealth on bright light, so spotting the gem should be automatic, unless the creature is attempting to hide it and it does make sense that it should be harder to see clearly.

Comment: I didn't write those rules, i cannot answer for the devs. But that specific phrasing has been corrected on other mentions of the rule:
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/forest-terrain

Comment: "The background noise in the forest makes Perception checks that rely on sound more difficult, increasing the DC of the check by 2 per 10 feet, not 1."

Comment: Also, you cannot dismiss a rule completely because of a bad example.

Comment: Aparently, this has been corrected on paizo's PRD: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/perception.html#perception

Comment: These rules should be considered carefully though, because it's well known that the human eye can spot a candlelight from miles away in a new moon's night. We can also spot airplanes on the sky that are thousands of miles away. That's why i said that things that should be obvious shouldnt require any check at all.

Comment: The "rule" you are citing is: "For example, bright light might increase the DC of checks involving sight, while torchlight or moonlight might give a penalty". The strange structure of the phrase seems enough to me to conclude that the one who wrote that example though about "increase of the DC" as an opposition to "a penalty", which is actually the opposite. Moreover this is just an example in some comment of a figure -and we all know there are mistakes in these figures, like casters who should loose spells when gaining a level- and should not be used blindly. Here there is "optimal lighting".

Comment: You are correct, i will edit it while referencing from the PRD.